# overflow content across elements

Tags: html, css

I have two DIV elements side-by-side, to create two columns. The two elements both have a fixed height of ~200px (calculated based on window height). I would like the content to overflow from the left DIV into the right, ONLY when the first DIV is full.

Unfortunately, I can't use CSS columns, since it automatically balances content across the columns, instead of filling the first column completely before overflowing.

So far the only option I've found (including here on SO) involves JS, and since the content may include HTML (including block elements), the use of JS is just about my least desirable approach.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe giving the code that you have right now would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something called [CSS regions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-regions/) and it is only a working draft atm.

"The CSS Regions module allows content from one or more elements to flow through one or more boxes called CSS Regions..."

Until then, I'd go with a [polyfill](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/03/10/css-regions-polyfill-better-smarter-fuller/).